# How to use overloading with multiple function signatures in TypeScript (overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature)?

Tags: typescript, function, overloading

I have [this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7OAXjgHIN8A3YWEuAH1IDNoBbAQxhICgvRJY4bAM6I8GOIwCuYnPjgY2AG0UAeAJJxQMYHgAmQuAGFK1GGrxhJMANols7AObASAXVvYLV1wD4AFFzhBLFw8AC5ScjwqGgAaALghCEkoDGBw4yjTNUdgAHVsGAALbLYnAFlS7AwAa3VvOIBKcIAFKAgWbCFgFQzomAB5K0sYb15waHhhUXEpGRD5JUV-QLZg-HCSZih2TjjAxOTU8IAxVg4AJUkhGEaWto6ulVPtjkGYYdG+CcERMQlpNYEBTKFRoTQgbR6AyYWR4PyrWHhNAxBJJFJpQR4RANOAAb3iQgA7gUMIU4L4ESEcfjAoEFF0IiYaKF4rS4FBgDBkgQ2IS2AV5EyYL4DuiGqyFgzNmdOCy2YEOVyoDy+QKtjsRWjUuLAgBfLj6rhTP6zQESGWaw4YthY6nxAD09rgYEVOl0cF0EDghOg1QAdAGHU7Fdy4El3lYJNhFKgwBxCnL2ZzQzTaYxoxjU2y40UNgAjNhQbhs-V6g08Y0zAGwwWZWCW9HhG3YvFB52uvQer0+qD+wOBR1JpUEcPDKMx53xxMh5WttnpmPhLO0nMJpgQCDF2mluD6w1fARIFBwZ47czDNTaFhEOdwDzDJtY+JaN2PxDlsb8eBH1Cnjjnqx8iKABRCEdCEEIVAAFXBSF9BPGUALMK9vBvVN7ysJcJXVDhwig9xPE4Fx4j3OAADIEJeGBQMhCD8Gg2wXz0HweAPb9kF-GUaPAyDgNgt0DFxc0qLfXdUOIfoOhgFR4mAvZ1yo7hRk-b4f0onY3jHYhU3IXQMWuKAPAcD82IQDijCFEonCA4ocgqBwqlqeINCY+CrOAezHKQv8bi4cTbwwmAsPnGVwjUEj4lHTDb0CHCgrgUCMEUSQ9J6SzCPcHJXFsKKiJRNRRjLXVyIsutqLAvA6LwNKyqQzLSmcNwSFcliVMPczelMbjKt4-ioTxO9CLfABuMMhmi5sxKIeJJIKFQ5NIQLaAYEhcpIVCKOXQLwlm6TgII4ZXBRaVFMK2lcp2qT5py8a8oUnZ1oitr2OPTrYCQtC20YRgWBQBxgrgQdAm2k8fr+ny20CC7Qd+4AHAhgcnUCVz0iFAA1bA9IgGzjjBuGADkID0pC2x3QdFA4UAAH0YAgKmwDwf7byBwaH1KvoABlKZAKCIGaRnvJlSGxojeK3pgLntB5vnGc0qwEcBpG+t0VGysl0Bef5hxCeJwjSfiewGoB4GhrgdzPJqQWqIlaHzcqGo5ZgBXkYqlX2ayHIbLthyah14ASaK1jxna17LM9gpbIai3qj9j7tPiQobV0RdSBfZUlC3EHlzisK7Pt6orZ2bCM2NlcpwSGBDMZiUdx3aHs9Cs28596pHed8dgAAflLwJV3CAyjJriLe-jABlcgUG7iuq+MukIEUaBjGkGAp7wSQWDzah4j0nqkFX9fN6geIAEdJCUApEH3jet-3YP4Eia4zbKNAAHFgKp5+X7UQwAGkqbUfGzQACqUEqbHH6OcZ+MFiDWHiGQKAAAmEg8kSAOUYMguBDMHAYMCCQAAVmAbBXAXA-FrNcIOX4zLHm9l5QiPlpqBF8D+CAjAn6v3fp-b+f8AHANAeAyBaAoINGsGva+UBiKmQfvANQn8OGvy4VTfoIDeFgIgVAm8sDcFYJwaQAhRCSHCDITAChqlzI0IdrdehhB4hMI4iwthb8P7yN-oo5RIDVECKESIg+1BiLPSoagcWjtPqxRLjFScuZp6D0Dv4tSPlLiP2ID5JCNlupVSeIhDKJAoBXCIspUycTMlaWZk6JKNomaphZiDQwFNGYKxZijdSHBjB6RsjU8pPlY560RruNswgugb0UIgAGVTTYkGECwLcDTXYnBlGgIQAy8xDK6cMfWCpcmlxBtk3JW4XZwVmVRBJMAVlWAirfShhTDm5JOfAeOgRE56BTs1MC6dFBbhzlE6uJs2bZzCcuEekSB5fO3MPEWPzi4xinv8iJa4gWzxBWWAFhRx4QEnv3Sug9dRAA), which demonstrates the error I'm getting right up top. It's a generic error message that's not very helpful:

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)
input.tsx(11, 23): The implementation signature is declared here.
function call(action: 'format', source: FormatRust): Promise<FormatOutput> (+1 overload)
```

Essentially, I have two functions, `format` and `convert`, which I wrap into a `call` function. In my production code, `format` has about 20 overload signatures (which all work), and `convert` has a similar number of overload signatures. Now I'm trying to combine them into the `call` function, but am getting a hard-to-make-sense-of error. The TypeScript code is pasted here too keep things colocated, but the TS playground shows in more detail the error.

```
export type Action = 'convert' | 'format'

export async function call<I extends ConvertInput['image']['input']>(
  action: 'convert',
  source: ConvertImageWithImageMagick<I>,
): Promise<ConvertOutput>
export async function call(
  action: 'format',
  source: FormatRust,
): Promise<FormatOutput>
export async function call<A extends Action>(action: A, source: any) {
  switch (action) {
    case 'convert':
      return await convert(source)
    case 'format':
      return await format(source)
  }
}

async function format(source: any) {
  // pretend do work...
  // return output file path:
  return {
    file: {
      path: 'bar'
    }
  }
}

async function convert(source: any) {
  // pretend do work...
  // return output file path:
  return {
    file: {
      path: 'foo'
    }
  }
}

export type FormatInputItem = {
  input: any
  extend: any
}

export type FormatInputWithExtension<T extends FormatInputItem> = {
  input: {
    format: T['input']
  }
} & FormatExtension<T['extend']>

export type FormatExtension<E extends { format: any }> = Omit<
  E,
  'format'
>

export type FormatOutput = {
  code: string
}

export type ConvertImageWithImageMagick<
  I extends ImageMagickInputFormat,
> = {
  input: {
    format: I
  }
  output: {
    format: Exclude<ConvertInput['image']['output'], I>
  }
} & ConvertExtension<ConvertInput['image']['extend']>

export type ConvertExtension<E extends { input: any; output: any }> =
  Omit<E, 'input' | 'output'> & {
    input: Omit<E['input'], 'format'>
    output: Omit<E['output'], 'format'>
  }

export type ConvertInput = {
  // ffmpeg: {
  //   input: FfmpegFormat
  //   output: FfmpegFormat
  //   extend: ConvertVideoWithFfmpegNodeInput
  // }
  // latex_to_png: {
  //   input: ConvertLatexToPngInputFormat
  //   output: ConvertLatexToPngOutputFormat
  //   extend: ConvertLatexToPngNodeInput
  // }
  image: {
    input: ImageMagickInputFormat
    output: ImageMagickOutputFormat
    extend: ConvertImageWithImageMagickNodeInput
  }
}

export type ConvertImageWithImageMagickNodeInput = {
  handle: 'external'
  input: {
    format: ImageMagickInputFormat
    file: {
      path: string
    }
  }
  output: {
    format: ImageMagickOutputFormat
    file?: {
      path: string
    }
  }
  pathScope?: string
  colorCount?: number
  density?: number
  quality?: number
}

export const IMAGE_MAGICK_INPUT_FORMAT = [
  'cr2',
  'gif',
  'png',
  'jpg'
] as const

export type ImageMagickInputFormat =
  (typeof IMAGE_MAGICK_INPUT_FORMAT)[number]
export const IMAGE_MAGICK_OUTPUT_FORMAT = [
  'png',
  'jpg'
] as const

export type ImageMagickOutputFormat =
  (typeof IMAGE_MAGICK_OUTPUT_FORMAT)[number]

export type ConvertOutput = {
  file: {
    path: string
  }
}

export type FormatRust = FormatInputWithExtension<FormatInput['rust']>

export type FormatInput = {
  // clang: {
  //   input: ClangFormat
  //   extend: FormatCodeWithClangFormatNodeInput
  // }
  // assembly: {
  //   input: 'asm'
  //   extend: FormatAssemblyNodeInput
  // }
  rust: {
    input: 'rust'
    extend: FormatRustNodeInput
  }
}

export type FormatRustNodeInput = {
  handle: 'external'
  format: string
  input: {
    file: {
      path: string
    }
  }
  output: {
    file?: {
      path: string
    }
  }
  pathScope?: string
}
```

How do I get the `call` function to support **not only these 2 divergent function signatures (convert/format), but also 10+ more sub-functions**, which also take a `source` property?

Here's a screenshot of my local code, which breaks at the first overload of `call(action: 'format', source...)`. This just goes to show that the error seems to be occurring *after* 10+ `convert` overloads, but at the *first* `format` overload. Even if I delete all the `call(action: 'convert')` ones, it still errors on the `format` ones, any idea how to get both of these (and potentially other similar subfunctions like `archive`, `inspect`, etc., to work in TypeScript?

[image]

Function overloading seems to be the best solution so far to my generic problem, but now I'm running into this, so not sure if there's a way to accomplish this that would work better *without* function overloading. Anything to allow composing 10+ nested functions (each with 10+ overloaded signatures), into one single `call` function. Function overloading solved a bunch of problems I was facing before, so ideally we can keep it, but I'm open to removing/changing it.

The main question is, how can I get more of an error message than just the nondescript "*overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature*"? How can I better debug this to find the cause of the error?

Comment: I can only comment on the code in the q, not your local code. Nothing in the `call()` body returns a `FormatOutput` (`format()` in particular does not), so the `call()` signature that returns `Promise<FormatOutput>` is not met. You can always assert that `format()` returns `FormatOutput` as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/mAa21m), but if that's not what you want then I think you might need to present a more illustrative [mre] (and note that most of the code in your example doesn't really matter for that error, so you should be able to whittle it down before adding extra stuff.)

Comment: This question was more about how can I get better at debugging that obscure meaningless error message. I figured it out eventually through deleting one-line-at-a-time until things worked, then going backwards. You are right, one of the functions wasn't returning the correct thing. @jcalz now I have a smaller, easily reproducible bug that is related and stumping me currently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093606/the-last-overload-gave-the-following-error-type-png-is-not-assignable-to

Comment: Given that TS warns on a given call signature, I'd manually check that call signature to see if the implementation inputs and possible outputs match. For your example it was easy enough to identify `FormatOutput` as being impossible. I agree that the error message isn't very helpful; there's an open issue for it at [ms/TS#48186](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48186). What do you want to do with this question? Should I write this up as an answer or do you think the question is obsolete and should be deleted?